# Installing Bugzilla 4.2.5 with Mysql 5.6.11

Tags: mysql, bugzilla

So now I am getting to the final steps of completing the Bugzilla install.  I keep getting 
'disabledtext' can't have a default value.

This is the complete error.

*Initializing "Dependency Tree Changes" email_setting ...
Updating column disabledtext in table profiles ...
Old: mediumtext DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
New: mediumtext NOT NULL

DBD::mysql::db do failed: BLOB/TEXT column 'disabledtext' can't have a default value [for Statement "ALTER TABLE profiles ALTER COLUMN disabledtext DROP DEFAULT"] at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 729.

Bugzilla::DB::bz_alter_column_raw('Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0x6e8f7f0)', 'profiles', 'disabledtext', 'HASH(0xa0a73d0)', 'HASH(0xa0be4a8)', undef) called at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 688

Bugzilla::DB::bz_alter_column('Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0x6e8f7f0)', 'profiles', 'disabledtext', 'HASH(0xa0a73d0)') called at Bugzilla/Install/DB.pm line 505

Bugzilla::Install::DB::update_table_definitions('HASH(0x30d53d0)') called at ./checksetup.pl line 199*

Is the actual error in Bugzilla/Install/DB.pm?

Very new at this stuff so any would be great.

Bugzilla = 4.2.5
Mysql = 5.6.11
OS = Suse 12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was an active bug filed for MySQL 5.6 and Bugzilla 4.2.5 and lower where mySQL 5.6 was not supported and causing a bunch of issues. The bug report is linked the the release notes below.

But to resolve your issue, you can either downgrade MySQL to a 5.5 series or lower, or upgrade BugZilla. [BugZilla 4.2.6](http://www.bugzilla.org/download/#oldstable) was released on May 22nd that provides support for MySQL 5.6, see the release notes linked off of [this page](http://www.bugzilla.org/news/#release44).

My advice is to upgrade BugZilla to 4.2.6.